# Docker Hub unofficial images for Snyk analysis

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I want to produce a little statistical research on Docker images, so I created a Python script that will return some images from Docker Hub. I will then use these image names to test with Snyk. The problem is that I am only getting official images, which are not interesting for statistics (0 errors). Is there a way to get unofficial images? I tested with API v2 using 'is_official=false' and 'image_filter=unofficial', but I am still getting the same error. Here is my code:

```
url = 'https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/?page_size=100&perating_system=linux&image_filter=open_source'


results = []

while len(results) < 1000:
    response = requests.get(url)
    json_data = response.json()
    for result in json_data['results']:
        name = result['name']
        results.append(name)
        if len(results) >= 1000:
            break
    if 'next' in json_data and json_data['next']:
        url = json_data['next']
    else:
        break

random_results = random.sample(results, min(len(results), 1000))
print(random_results)

# write results to file
with open('random_images.txt', 'w') as f:
    for image in random_results:
        f.write(image + '\n')
```

Comment: so what error are you getting? Can you please share it?

Comment: also note that you probably stress the rate limits with your code. Fetching 1000 images, without being looged in, is probably not allowed.

Comment: @TheFool I am getting all official images(instead of unofficial), they all have 0 critical vulnerability.

Comment: Ok but you say *I am still getting the same error.*. So its probably good to include that error in your question.

Comment: @TheFool, yes I have another version of this code, where I am using my login, pw and token, but there was an error and I abandoned that solution.You are right, I am getting 173 images, but even there I must to have some unofficial images,no?

Comment: I think the problem is that you use /library. This is the namespace used for *official* images, afaik. Still, please include the error.

Comment: @TheFool ok thanks, i will try to modify it